# c# label text won't update on usercontrol after button click

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a usercontrol that is loaded to a panel on Form1 in a winform application when a menu option is selected. The usercontrol has buttons that are used to fire the printer select dialog and allow the user to setup multiple printers for the application. Each button configures the settings property in the application to store a printer. Under each button there is a label that displays the name of the printer from the settings property.

I am using events to manage the button clicks from the usercontrol. Everything works great with the events storing the correct printer in the settings property. However, I want the label to display the selected printer immediately after I select it in the printer dialog. It won't display the change of printer until I navigate away from the usercontrol and back. Then it shows the correct printer name for each button.

I am able to write to the label text just fine. I've tried refreshing the label, invalidating and updating the label. Nothing seems to work. Only navigating away and back will display the printer names in the labels.

Here is one of my button click handlers on Form1:

```
        private void btnTwoByHalf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ucPrinterSetup prn = new ucPrinterSetup();

        twoByHalf.PropName = "TwoByHalfPrn";
        twoByHalf.SetPrinter(twoByHalf.PropName);
        prn.lblTwoByHalf.Text = twoByHalf.Printer;
    }
```

Here is my menu option click handler:

```
        private void configurePrintersToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearFrames();

        ucPrinterSetup printerSetup = new ucPrinterSetup();
        pnlMenu.Controls.Add(printerSetup);

        printerSetup.btnTwoByHalfClick += new EventHandler(btnTwoByHalf_Click);
        printerSetup.btnFourByOneClick += new EventHandler(btnFourByOne_Click);
        printerSetup.btnFourByTwoFiveClick += new EventHandler(btnFourByTwoFive_Click);
        printerSetup.btnMiscClick += new EventHandler(btnMisc_Click);
        printerSetup.btnDefaultClick += new EventHandler(btnDefault_Click);
        printerSetup.btnSecondaryClick += new EventHandler(btnSecondary_Click);

        ucConfigurePrinters configurePrinters = new ucConfigurePrinters();
        pnlFrame.Controls.Add(configurePrinters);
    }
```

Here is my button click handler from ucPrinterSetup.cs:

```
        private void btnTwoByHalf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnTwoByHalfClick != null)
            btnTwoByHalfClick(sender, e);
    }
```

Everything else works fine. It just doesn't update the label.text after I select the new printer until I navigate away from ucPrinterSetup and back.

Update 1:
My printers are being stored in the application settings through:

```
        twoByHalf.PropName = "TwoByHalfPrn";
        twoByHalf.SetPrinter(twoByHalf.PropName);
```

twoByHalf.PropName is the name that I've pre-entered in the settings property for the application.

I then set the label text to the name of the printer with:

```
prn.lblTwoByHalf.Text = twoByHalf.Printer;
```

In Application-Settings I have preset printer names as:

```
TwoByHalfPrn - string - User - (no value)
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you're using .NET databinding to save the printer setup controls to the application settings?  If so, I think by default the settings object doesn't get updated until the control is validated (i.e. when focus is leaving the control).  You can change this from OnValidation to OnPropertyChanged in the Advanced dialog accessible from the property sheet under DataBindings.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. I don't see DataBindings on the property sheet.

Comment: Okay, maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in `prn.lblTwoByHalf.Text = twoByHalf.Printer;`, do you reach it? Also, what is 'prn' (is it the form or the control) and where do you assign it?

Comment: When I use a breakpoint, it does reach the label and it looks like the name of the printer is in the label.text value. prn is the instantiation of the usercontrol called ucPrinterSetup. That is the usercontrol that has the label.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem seems to be that you set the label on a control other than the one you are showing.
When your click event (`btnTwoByHalf_Click`) is called, you should use 
the user control that is currently showing, but instead you create a new one with `ucPrinterSetup prn = new ucPrinterSetup();`

This is not the same control that is showing, but a completely new control, so when you change the label in `prn` you change the label in an invisible control, the original control remains unchanged.

I can see 4 ways of getting the original control:

1.
You can get it from the menu. If you only have one instance of this control type in you menu, you can use something like (no error handling in my code):

```
 ucPrinterSetup prn = pnlMenu.Controls.OfType<ucPrinterSetup>().First();
 twoByHalf.PropName = "TwoByHalfPrn";
 twoByHalf.SetPrinter(twoByHalf.PropName);
 prn.lblTwoByHalf.Text = twoByHalf.Printer;
```

Or, if you do have more than one you can assign different names to your controls and use something like `pnlMenu.Controls.Find("YourControlNameGoesHere", false).First();`

2.
You can get it from the `sender` property in your event. The sender is the button in the control, so assuming the button is sitting directly in the control, the button's parent will be the control:

```
ucPrinterSetup prn = (ucPrinterSetup)((Control)sender).Parent);
```

If the button is not sitting directly in the control (for example, it might sit in a panel that sits in a control) then you might need to up the chain more, you can put a breakpoint in the event entry and inspect the sender.

3.
The third way is maybe the best, but it requires you to change your design. It seems that you create the control again and again each time the menu is clicked. Maybe there's a good reason for it, but assuming there's no real reason for it, it's probably better to create the user control once when you start, and just switch the original control in and out. Then you can just put your control in a class variable and use it from your event.

4.
And for completeness you can also use a lambda/anonymous method for your event and capture the control when you register the event.
If you do that, then in the method which you register the event, replace the registration code to something like this:

`printerSetup.btnTwoByHalfClick += (sender, e) => btnTwoByHalf_Click(printerSetup );`

And then change your event method signature and code to be like this:

```
private void btnTwoByHalf_Click(ucPrinterSetup prn)
{
    twoByHalf.PropName = "TwoByHalfPrn";
    twoByHalf.SetPrinter(twoByHalf.PropName);
    prn.lblTwoByHalf.Text = twoByHalf.Printer;
}
```

This might be the easiest code and less error prone to use, though notice that if you need to unregister the event later on, it might prove tricky.